# Where to place methods from a gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, methods, controller

I'm using the following [Acts as message](https://github.com/LTe/acts-as-messageable) gem for messages. The gem states that to mark a message as read do the following:

@message.mark_as_read

Below is my code in which I'm iterating over each message and then I'm trying to mark the message a read in the view, however this does not work. I get an error "Couldn't find Store with id=true"

Normally I would setup a method in the controller or model to handle the gem's method but I'm confused how I should do this given the gem refers to a table in the database and doesn't require a new model or controller. This is driving me crazy! Where should I put these methods (There are more like this)?

Any Ideas?

```
    <% @messages.each do |m| %>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <%= link_to 'Mark Read', "#{m.mark_as_read}", :class => 'btn btn-mini' %>           
        </td>
    </tr>

    <% end %>
```

**My Model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base 

  acts_as_messageable :table_name => "messages",                         # default 'messages'
                      :required   => [:topic, :body],                     # default [:topic, :body]
                      :class_name => "ActsAsMessageable::Message",       # default "ActsAsMessageable::Message",
                      :dependent  => :nullify                            # default :nullify
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot simply add a link which calls a method like you're doing above.

Here's what is happening with your code: <%= link_to 'Mark Read', "#{m.mark_as_read}" %>

The m.mark_as_read is called when the template is parsed, so all your messages are actually already marked as read when your page is rendered. Since m.mark_as_read is returning true, you get the html `<a href='true'>Mark Read</a>` which is causing the error you specified as it routes to that path.

What you need to do here is create an action(preferably in MessagesController) where you can mark the message as read, and then point your link to that address,